# NGINX URLS rewrite

Tags: nginx

I am former Apache user who has decided to take the plunge and move over to NGINX. On Apache I had some rewrite rules as set out below.
I have two questions:

1. Can anybody help me with the NGINX version of these rewrites?
2. How do I apply the rewrites to all sites on the server?

Thank you in advance

```
# 301 Redirect http to https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 301 Redirect www to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove the .html extension
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

# Remove index and reference the directory
    RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# Remove trailing slash if not a directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
    RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# Forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
```

UPDATE
After trawling through many articles I think that I have come up with the following solutions - please feel free to comment and advise:

```
    server {
        # Catch all and redirects to https
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
      # Redirect www to https
      server_name www.example.com;
      return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/example.key;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

      location / {
          root   /var/www/example.com/html;
          index  index.html;

          # Remove .html extension
          if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html) {
              return 302 /$1;
          }
          try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
      }
```

The issues that I haven't resolved are:

1. Remove trailing slash if not a directory
2. Forward request to html file  but don't redirect (bot friendly)

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very easy task so don't be afraid. I am sharing two documents with you from where you can easily get to know about all rewriting rules in Nginx.

Convert Apache rewrite rules to Nginx -  https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Create Nginx rewrite rules - https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

If you face any problem during the conversion just mention it in the comment. I will add that in the answer.

Comment: Hello Lovekesh, thank you for the links. I'm working through them at the moment and will post updates.